# Deixar página atual destacada em um menu de seleção de páginas?

Tags: php, html, dwoo, template

Tenho um menu de seleção de páginas cuja a aparência final (a página que atual destacada com uma cor diferente) deve ser gerada dinamicamente pois desejo reaproveitar o mesmo menu para inúmeras páginas, como farei esta marcação dinâmica?

Imagem de como deverá ficar o menu (com a página que estou destacada):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código HTML renderizado do menu estático:

```
<div id="left_sidebar" class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="hardware-statistics.php">Hardware Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="hardware-logs.php">Hardware Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="software-statistics.php">Softwares Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="software-logs.php">Softwares Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="site-statistics.php">Site Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="site-logs.php">Site Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="advertises-statistics.php">Advertises Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="advertises-logs.php">Advertises Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="notices-warnings-errors.php">Notices, Warnings and Errors
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notem que faço o destaque da página que estou por meio de uma classe

**OBS1:** Estou usando um **Template Engine** o `Dwoo Template 2.0` para gerar a interface da aplicação (incluindo o menu).

**OBS2:** Estou usando o `PHP` para criar os dados que são passados para o array de dados (dados que é passado ao objeto dwoo para preenchimento do html).

Comment: Respondi minha própria pergunta da forma que encontrei pra resolver o problema, se alguém tiver uma solução melhor publique que validarei sem problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando a instrução `if` suportada pelo `Dwoo Template` faço uma comparação entre o nome de cada página e o endereço da página atual que está dentro de uma variável passada pelo array de dados (dados que é passado ao objeto dwoo para preenchimento do html).

O código do template fica da seguinte forma:

```
<div id="left_sidebar" class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'dashboard.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'hardware-statistics.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="hardware-statistics.php">Hardware Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'hardware-logs.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="hardware-logs.php">Hardware Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'software-statistics.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="software-statistics.php">Softwares Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'software-logs.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="software-logs.php">Softwares Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'site-statistics.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="site-statistics.php">Site Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'site-logs.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="site-logs.php">Site Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'advertises-statistics.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="advertises-statistics.php">Advertises Statistics
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'advertises-logs.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="advertises-logs.php">Advertises Logs
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"
            {if 'notices-warnings-errors.php' == $page}
                class="active"
            {/if}
            ><a href="notices-warnings-errors.php">Notices, Warnings and Errors
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

e a página em si que é acessada via browser fica da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

    require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

    $dwoo = new Dwoo\Core();
    $dwoo->setCompileDir('../../../assets/compiled/');
    $dwoo->setTemplateDir('../../../assets/templates/');

    $data = array();

    $data['page'] = 'dashboard.php';
    $dwoo->output('dashboard.tpl', $data);
?>
```

assim em cada nova página criada com php pode-se mudar o valor da posição `page` do array de dados pondo o nome da página
acessada.

Comment: Respondi minha própria pergunta da forma que encontrei pra resolver o problema, se alguém tiver uma solução melhor publique que validarei sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer com jQuery (ou Javascript puro se achar melhor):

```
jQuery(document).load(function($){

   var page = window.location.pathname;

   // remove qualquer parâmetro de url 
   // por exemplo de 'pagina.php?id=10' para 'pagina.php'
   page = page.replace(/\?.+/, ''); 

   // Caso seja uma url amigavel e queria apenas o primeiro parâmetro
   // por exemplo de 'pagina/produto/fogao' para 'pagina'
   page = page.split('/')[0]; 

   // Aplica a classe
   $('#left_sidebar a[href="' + page + '"]').parent() // Seleciona pai
                                          .addClass('active') // Adiciona classe
                                          .siblings() // Seleciona irmãos
                                          .removeClass('active'); // Remove classe
});
```

Comment: como eu passaria esta variável $page para o arquivo .js?

Comment: Bem, esse javascript poderia estar logo após o menu (sem o `(document).load`). Mas poderia utilizar o `window.location.pathname` @ricardo

Comment: Atualizei a respota @ricardo...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar se a página atual for a página do conteúdo que você abriu, a classe "active" é impressa. Exemplo:

```
<li role="presentation"<?php echo ($page == 'dashboard') ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>
     <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</li>
<li role="presentation"<?php echo ($page == 'hardware-statistics') ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>
  <a href="hardware-statistics.php">Hardware Statistics <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</li>
```